# How can I move certificates from 1 server to another

Tags: ssl

I'm using StartSSL which , after you proove who you say you are, provides a certificate which I can install to authenticate myself. I have some SSL certificates associated with this account.

I've bought a new server, and I need to move the certificates over, but I'm failing.

On my 'old W28k server', I went into Firefox, and viewed the certificates. I then exported them all, zipped them up and emailed them to my new W2012  server.

On my new server, I've registered with StartSSL and can authenticate, but now realise I have to use my old certificate.

When I open the certificate it shows I can install it, which I do, and the wizard gives the option to let it choose the best place to install it.

I've done, but when I now go to StartSLL I can't get authenticated.

Have I installed the certification incorrectly?

Comment: The certificate is only part of what you need. You also need to copy the private key from the old server.

Comment: @EEAA, the certificate was exportable from the Certficiates section in the browser. Is the private key in the same place or else where?

Comment: The key is not exportable through the browser. Think about that: if it were, anyone could export your key and certificate and then impersonate your site. I'm not familiar enough with Windows to give you further guidance, but you'll likely need to use the IIS tools or another command-line tool to export the private key.

Comment: @EEAA but their website suggests to do this (If I understood their instructions correctly) See the section about the handshake failure- https://www.startssl.com/?app=25#10

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions the confusion here arises from the lack of clarity in your question. Your title being "how can I move certificates from 1 server to another" would tend to suggest the more common task of moving SSL/TLS certificates from one (web?)server to another, but in your case you are moving a personal identification certificate (which arguably you wouldn't normally even use on a server to request new SSL/TLS certs anyway, but on your own machine for example).

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions if you aren't able to successfully export your personal identification certificate either using the steps to export it from Firefox as linked above, nor in the steps I have listed below in my answer from the computer's own certificate store, then you will likely need to create a new account with StartSSL and notify them to merge the old account (this is their standard practice in that case, and the only option should you lose access to your personal identification cert).

Comment: oh.... @BE77Y, I just did it all from the 1 place... Are you saying I'd do this on the local computer, get authenticated, and then request the certs and copy and paste keys around is the more 'common' approach

Comment: @BE77Y, I did - they merged everything to my OLD account :(

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions no, what I'm saying is that you should identify whether you only imported them to Firefox, or also to the local computer store - then choose one of the two methods to export the key and cert to be re-imported. If they merged to your old account for which you no longer have the cert/key then you will need to start again and re-merge.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I have added the explicit steps to export from Firefox to my answer - as I have said, if you cannot export or find the appropriate cert there, then check your machine store as per my answer. If you still cannot find it - you will need to create a new account and have it merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export the certificate as a whole - not just the certificate itself but also the private key, as pointed out by @EEAA in the comments below your question.

As per [the MS documentation on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329.aspx):

> 1. Open the Certificates snap-in for a user, computer, or service.
> 2. In the console tree under the logical store that contains the certificate to export, click Certificates.
> 3. In the details pane, click the certificate that you want to export.
> 4. On the Action menu, point to All Tasks, and then click Export.
> 5. In the Certificate Export Wizard, click Yes, export the private key. (This option will appear only if the private key is marked as
>      exportable and you have access to the private key.)
> 6. Under Export File Format, do any of the following, and then click Next. To include all certificates in the certification path, select
>      the Include all certificates in the certification path if possible
>      check box.To delete the private key if the export is successful,
>      select the Delete the private key if the export is successful check
>      box.To export the certificate's extended properties, select the Export
>      all extended properties check box.
> 7. In Password, type a password to encrypt the private key you are exporting. In Confirm password, type the same password again, and then
>      click Next.
> 8. In File name, type a file name and path for the PKCS #12 file that will store the exported certificate and private key. Click Next, and
>      then click Finish.

You more or less need to reverse these steps on the new server to import the certificate and private key there.

**EDIT:** it's also worth noting, that since you mention in your question that you attempted exporting these personal identification certificates from Firefox, that you should identify whether or not you did indeed import the personal identification certificate to Firefox only or also to the system's certificate store (for use in IE and/or Chrome for example, whereas Firefox uses its own certificate store). 
Finally you might find it useful to use the [StartSSL FAQ](https://www.startssl.com/?app=25) for such issues in future as a first-port-of-call. To back up the client certificate from Firefox, follow these steps [from the StartSSL FAQ page](https://www.startssl.com/?app=25#4):

> Select "Preferences|Options" -> "Advanced" -> "Certificates" -> "View
>   Certificates", choose the "Your Certificates" tab and locate your
>   client certificate from the list. The certificate will be listed under
>   StartCom. Select the certificate and click on "Backup", choose a name
>   for this backup file, provide a password and save it at a known
>   location. Now you should either burn this file to a CD ROM or save it
>   on a USB stick or smart card. Thereafter delete this file from your
>   computer.

Comment: This is the problem, I have no back up option... Only export. Your details way go to Encryption tab, I don't have that, only a Certificates tab. I click View Certificates and find the StartCom in the list - my options are View, Edit Trust, Import, Export, Delete or Distrust! If I export, I am not prompted to provided a password. I also have half a dozen certs, I assume I need to do this with the Class 2 certificate (which is a Software Security Device)?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the wrong tab - you need the 'Your Certificates' tab, which is the left-most tab in the certificate manager on the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: I don't believe it. I was on the wrong tab. I'd seen in the instructions, I'd read the instruction, I just didn't follow them. Thanks for being so patient!

Answer (score 1):

If you could export full certificates with private keys from a browser that would make them pointless!
You need to use the export feature ON the server, and then import on your new server.

See these guides:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771103.aspx

Answer (score 1):

So, as far as I understand, you don't ask about importing/exporting SSL Certificates in gerneral (e.g. the ones you use for IIS) but the client authentication certificate from StartSSL?

In that case, you have to re-import it into Firefox. To do this, got to Options --> Advanced --> Certificates --> View Certificates --> on the Tab "My Certificates" --> Import

You can then log in to StartSSL.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is super, but I get an error message. According to their help https://www.startssl.com/?app=25#10 , I need to export the certs with the keys. How to export the certifcates with the private key?

Comment: In Firefox: Options --> Advanced --> Certificates --> View Certificates --> on the Tab "My Certificates" select the one you want to export --> Backup. In the save dialog window choos PKCS12 format, this should contain the private key

Answer (score 0):

You can export both the cert, and the key using this procedure:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329.aspx  One thing to note however is 
"A private key is exportable only when it is specified in the certificate request"

If the key is exportable the cert export wizard will give you the option.  If its non-exportable there are a few tools (jailbreak for non-64 bit systems, and mimkatz) that say they can export non exportable keys but I have no experience with them so I have no clue how well they work.